# Trying to compare the two strings inside the linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to check the equality on two strings using the `EF Functions` like a method, but it is failing somehow and getting null on spaces.
The two strings are like as below, Here you can observe the only difference is the case for `SPACE`

the displayName is `L1-008-5 SPACE` and I have stored Displayname in space identity object as like this `L1-008-5 Space`

`L1-008-5 SPACE` and `L1-008-5 Space`

Here is the code

```
 var space = dbContext.Spaces.SingleOrDefault(a => EF.Functions.Like(a.SpaceIdentity.DisplayName, displayName));
```

and I tried the below options as well

```
dbContext.Spaces.SingleOrDefault(s => s.SpaceIdentity.DisplayName.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

dbContext.Spaces.SingleOrDefault(s => string.Equals(s.SpaceIdentity.DisplayName,displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

None of the above are working and getting null on spaces.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction where I am doing wrong with the above comparison.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to give some example inputs and outputs. Also, what is in `displayName`?

Comment: @DavidG i have modified the question

Comment: So you're looking for a case insensitive search?

Comment: yeah with those strings

Comment: What's your database's collation setting for the DisplayName field?

Comment: LIKE queries are affected by the collation setting for the database, what is that set to?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL and I cannot change the  DB schema without that I am looking for an alternative here. Unfortunately, the `SpaceIndentity` object is stored as a JSON column  in spaces table.

Comment: This might help? https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/api/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL) provider for EF Core, you should have access to the [`ILike`](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/api/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions.html#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions_ILike_DbFunctions_System_String_System_String_) method which is a case-insensitive `LIKE`. That means you are able to use this code:

```
var space = dbContext.Spaces
    .SingleOrDefault(a => 
        EF.Functions.ILike(a.SpaceIdentity.DisplayName, displayName));
//                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: That works, thanks for input.